# Detect opening of new file in same excel window

Tags: c#, excel

I have made an excel ribbon. In that ribbon, there are few buttons which I want to disable if the filename doesn't contain specific string. So I put the logic in ExcelRibbon_load() event. But the problem is ExcelRibbon_Load() is fired only at the time of opening new excel window. If user opens correct file afterwards in the same window, the buttons would remain disabled.So, I want to detect the opening of new file in same excel window (Like File->Open->FileName) programmatically via C#. Any idea how to achieve this. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I have changed my question for your understanding. Please have a look at it and suggest something.